# Laravel 5.1 update pivot table column without dropping existing records

Tags: laravel

I am using `Laravel 5.1`.

I have two tables namely `users` and `medicines` with `many-to-many` relationship. The related `models` are as below:

```
class User extends BaseModel  {

    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    protected $table = 'users';

    public function medicines(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Medicine')->withPivot('id', 'time','config' ,'start','end' );
    }
}
```

and

```
class Medicine extends BaseModel{

    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    protected $table = 'medicines';

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User')->withPivot('id', 'time','config' ,'start','end'  );
    }
}
```

The `many-to-many` relational table `user_medicine` having some additional `pivot columns` as below:

```
id(PK) user_id(FK users) medicine_id(FK medicines) time   config        start       end 
1      1                 41                        09:00  {dispense:2}  2015-12-01  2015-12-25
2      1                 43                        10:00  {dispense:1}  2015-12-10  2015-12-22
3      1                 44                        17:00  NULL          2015-12-10  2015-12-31
```

Now, I want to change the time of specific medicine. That I have made codes as below:

```
public function updateMedicationTime($fields){

    $result = array();

    try {
        $user = User::find($fields['user_id']); 

        $medicines = $user->medicines()->where('medicines.id',$fields['medicine_id'])->first();

        if (!empty($medicines)){
            $medicine_times = json_decode($medicines->pivot->time);

            foreach ($medicine_times as $key=>$medicine_time ){

                if ($medicine_time->time == $fields['oldtime']){

                    $medicine_time->time = $fields['newtime'];
                }
            }

            // Update the time column of provided medicine id
            $user->medicines()->where('medicines.id',$fields['medicine_id'])->sync(array($medicines->id , array("time"=>json_encode($medicine_times))), false);

            // I also have tried 

            // $medicines->sync(array($medicines->id , array("time"=>json_encode($medicine_times))), false); OR 
            // $medicines->pivot->sync(array($medicines->id , array("time"=>json_encode($medicine_times))), false);

        }

    }
    catch(Exception $e ){
        throw $e;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

But rather than `updating` the exiting `many-to-many` table's time column, it is `inserting` a new record with medicine `id = 1` with provided `time` and `null` other columns. Can anyone suggest where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 6):

There is a method called `updateExistingPivot` that you can use:

```
$user = User::find($id);
$user->medicines()->updateExistingPivot($medicine_id, ['time' => $time], false);
```

The last parameters specifies if the parent table should be "touched", meaning that the timestamps of the `updated_at` fields are updated.